# In this HTML double dropdown, how can the first dropdown not be obscured by the second button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

When the first dropdown is showing, part of it is obscured by the button from the second dropdown. How can this be fixed? This is a case abstracted from a larger code. In the actual case, the second dropdown actually unexpectedly pops up, not down (although there seems to be space enough), so the obscuring action is reciprocal: not only does does the second obscure a choice when the first is open, but also the first obscures a choice from the second when it opens upwards.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function myFunction1() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown1").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    function optclick1(option) {
     var txt = "Mode: "+option;
     document.getElementById("dropbut1").innerText = txt;
    }
    
    function optclick2(option) {
     var txt = "Made: "+option;
     document.getElementById("dropbut2").innerText = txt;
    }
    
    // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
   /* Dropdown Button */
    .dropbtn {
        /*background-color: white;
        color: black;
        border: none;
        */
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    /* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
    
    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    /* Links inside the dropdown */
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        /*padding: 12px 16px;*/
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    
    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
    
    /* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the 
       .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the 
       dropdown button) */
       
    .show {display:block;}
```

```html
 
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>testdrop</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
     <div class="dropdown">
      <button id="dropbut1" onclick="myFunction1()" class="dropbtn">Mode: Link 1</button>
      <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#" onclick="optclick1('Link 1');">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="optclick1('Link 2');">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="optclick1('Link 3');">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
     <div class="dropdown">
      <button id="dropbut2" onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn">Made: Chain 1</button>
      <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#" onclick="optclick2('Chain 1');">Chain 1</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="optclick2('Chain 2');">Chain 2</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="optclick2('Chain 3');">Chain 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#myDropdown1 {
 z-index:1;
}
```

Give the dropdown div a z index.

or use class to give style

```
.dropdown-content {
   z-index: 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change one piece of CSS: in your `.dropdown-content`, change `position` from `absolute` to `relative`. This will make it so that the drop-down menu will move the other button when it opens.

Your new CSS block for `dropdown-content` will be:

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```